All 3 forefathers called "Yisroel"?
B"H
I heard that there's a midrash that says that all 3 of the forefathers, Avraham, Yitzhak and Yaakov were all called Yisroel.
Is this true? If so where is it found?

See the attached text (Bereshis 63:3) and commentary copied from the ArtScroll Midrash Rabbah


